# Python - Add leading zeros to digits in date in CSV file

Tags: python, date, data-conversion

Using Python 3.3 on Win8.  I would consider myself a novice at scripting.  I am trying to work with dates in an Excel spreadsheet with no leading zeros.  The year is always 2 digits at the end, month comes first and then day is in the middle.  I can extract the Excel column to place it solely on its own in a file.  Below are some examples of what I may run into with thousands of lines to go through and fix the dates into recognizable formats:

1188 (mdyy)
11188 (problem date)
12188 (problem date)
13188 (mddyy)
21188 (mddyy)
111188 (mmddyy)

I guess I have 2 parts to my question:
(1) What type of file is easiest to work with when modifying using Python (ex. XLSX, XLS, CSV, TXT, etc)
(2) Any tips on coding the below logic with Python...maybe functions to use?

Below is my logic I would like to apply because I know there is not way to actually tell if the dates only have 5 digits and start with an "11" or "12", so I want to place ERROR instead so we can go back to manually fix those.  The idea is less manual labor, the better.

- Always 2 digit for year at the end, so it needs parsed out right away with remaining digits left

  - IF year digits from "00" to "30" THEN attach a leading "20" to form a 4 digit year
  - Else attach a leading "19" to form a 4 digit year
- Count number of digits left after taking away year digits

  - IF total digits left = 2 THEN parse out first and second digits, AND add leading zero to both digits
  - ElseIF total digits left = 3 THEN

    - IF first two numbers are "11" or "12", print final results as "ERROR"
    - ElseIF first two numbers are "10" THEN parse out as is AND add leading zero to third digit
    - Else parse out first digit AND add leading zero THEN parse out remaining 2 digits as is
  - Else total digits left = 4, THEN do nothing
- Make sure date is put back together in new format for final result

### Thanks so much for any help and a kick start to go off on my own!

MY JOURNEY

### Initially I needed help getting my logic into Python, then battled the following but was successful in the end with time, research and helpful people at stackoverflow: reading/writing/appending CSV files, fill leading zeros, fill leading digits for year, syntax, incorrect data types, etc...THANKS TO ALL THAT HELPED!!!

FINALIZED CODE BELOW!!!!!!!

```
import csv
# Change to location of CSV file
with open('c:\\Users\\Weez\\Desktop\\csv_test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in csvreader:
        baddate = line[0]
        year = int(baddate) % 100
        md = int(baddate) // 100
# Check year values
        if year < 10:
            year = str(200)+str(year)
        elif year <= 50:
            year = str(20)+str(year)
        else:
            year = str(19)+str(year)
# Check month and day values
        if md < 100:
            month = md // 10
            month = str(month).zfill(2)
            day = md % 10
            day = str(day).zfill(2)
        elif md >= 1000:
            pass
        elif md <= 109:
            month = md // 10
            day = md % 10
            day = str(day).zfill(2)
        elif md == 110:
            month = md // 100
            month = str(month).zfill(2)
            day = md % 100
        elif md == 120:
            month = md // 100
            month = str(month).zfill(2)
            day = md % 100
        elif md <= 129:
            month = str("XX")
            day = str("XX")
        else:
            month = md // 100
            month = str(month).zfill(2)
            day = md % 100
        dateresult = str(month)+str(day)+str(year)
        print(dateresult)
# modes 'a' = append, 'w' = write, 'r' = read and other modes
        with open('c:\\Users\\Weez\\Desktop\\csv_test_output.csv', 'a') as csvoutput:
            csvoutput.write(dateresult)
            csvoutput.write('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
str(input("Process complete!  Press Enter to finish!"))
```

Comment: On part 1) you can either use the xlrd package to read xlsx or xls files. Or just use the built in csv package to read csv files.

Comment: Thanks!  I read about the CSV package and am thinking about using that.  Since I haven't used it before, I wasn't sure if those would be easier to work with or if a plain text file with one number per line would be easier.

Comment: No need to close the file at the end, the `with` statement does that automatically.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I tried commenting that out with no luck. Same error message.  I tried different indentation and that gave me a new error, so that might have been the problem.  Still working through errors and will post final if I can get there.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Indent all that stuff so it's within the `with` statement, up to the point you had the `close`. The csv reader won't read the file all at once so it needs to stay open.

Comment: Almost there!  One last error writing the file to a CSV and I should be golden as everything else seems to work.  See above for error and I also provided it here:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AddLeadZeroToDate.py", line 49, in <module>
    writer.writerow(dateresult)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the year is always two digits, you can eliminate that part of the problem right away.

```
year = date % 100
md = date // 100
```

Now you can eliminate the 2-digit and 4-digit cases:

```
if md < 100:
    month = md / 10
    day = md % 10
elif md >= 1000:
    month = md / 100
    day = md % 100
```

Now you're down to detecting the potential problem areas and resolving the ambiguity.

```
elif md <= 109:
    month = 10
    day = md % 10
elif md == 110:
    month = 1
    day = 10
elif md <= 129:
    month = None # ambiguous
    day = None
else:
    month = md / 100
    day = md % 100
```

You'll need to do some additional checking to make sure the month and day are within bounds.

Comment: Thanks!  I am currently trying some of this out and I like the logic you use as it's easy to follow for a novice.  I am using the following to add leading zeros, which I just found looking elsewhere:    month = str(month).zfill(2)

Comment: I like the fact that this one specifically flags (in a way that's obvious to a novice) when you've hit a possibly ambiguous date and need to look at the data and see whether there's a way out of the problem (e.g., Peter Gibson's suggestion of looking at the order) or whether it's just not solvable, so you have to just fall back to putting "ERROR" there and fixing it manually later.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I used your logic to write my own code, which works flawlessly when giving the variable one date and printing the output at the end.  When I try to use the CSV function, I have run into errors.  One error dealing with passing a list to a function looking for an integer which I understand but the other I listed by editing my original post above.  See update...any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For #1 you can use `csv` though I don't have any experience with other modules :(.

For #2, You can use builtin module, `datetime`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> date_unpadded_month = '1188'
>>> date_padded_month = '01188'
>>> date_2_digit_month = '11188'
>>> date_format = '%m%d%y'

>>> parsed = datetime.strptime(date_unpadded_month, date_format)
>>> parsed
>>> datetime.datetime(1988, 1, 1, 0, 0)

>>> parsed = datetime.strptime(date_padded_month, date_format)
>>> parsed
>>> datetime.datetime(1988, 1, 1, 0, 0)

>>> parsed = datetime.strptime(date_2_digit_month, date_format)
>>> parsed
>>> datetime.datetime(1988, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parsed.month
>>> 11
```

Comment: In the case when you are not sure the second digit belongs to month or day field, you can either change the `date_format` to '%m%dd%y' which will error out when the date is in incorrect form but will error out when '1188' date too. If you want the exact behavior you have specified, you need to code it explicitly before parsing.

Comment: `datetime.strptime('11188', '%m%dd%y')` gives `ValueError: time data '11188' does not match format '%m%dd%y'` for my on Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have the logic down but seem to have trouble with the CSV function now.  See my original post for an update...any ideas is appreciated.  I feel like I'm so close because my core code works but when using csv function with a file, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates in the spreadsheet are in order, you might be able to retroactively go back and fix previously ambiguous dates with a high level of success. For instance if you have

```
123087, 11188, 22288
```

The first and last dates are non-ambiguous (`Dec-30-'87` & `Feb-22-'88`), and the middle date is either `Jan-11-'88` or `Nov-1-'88`, but can be solved if you know that the three dates are in order.

Edit: here's some code for achieving this:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = '123087', '1188', '11188', '22288', '11188' # some 4, 5 and 6 digit dates
fmt = '%m%d%y'
results = []
# parse possible dates from data
for date_str in data:
    alt_date_str = ('0' + date_str)[-6:]
    dates = (datetime.strptime(d, fmt) for d in (date_str, alt_date_str))
    results.append(set(dates)) # make sure dates are unique

# iterate through results, removing anything older than the previous entries
oldest = datetime.min
for i in xrange(len(results)):
    results[i] = [d for d in results[i] if d > oldest]
    oldest = min(results[i])

# iterate backwards, removing anything newer than the previous entries
newest = datetime.max
for i in reversed(xrange(len(results))):
    results[i] = [d for d in results[i] if d < newest]
    newest = max(results[i])

# show dates, error if still ambiguous
for dates in results:
    if len(dates) > 1:
        print 'ERROR:', dates
    else:
        print dates[0]
```

Comment: That's true but not sure if I can get it in order.  It may be worth fixing before running Python against it.  I could use regex to look for anything starting with "11" or "12" with exactly 3 characters following it like so: 1[1|2][0-9][0-9][0-9]